How to use modal verbs. Have to vs must

You must clean your room

You have to clean your room


What is the difference? I think it's vague. 1 could be an order from "you" or a strong recommendation dependent on your tone of voice. 2 could mean that "you" recommends something because it's good or repeats someone else's order. Biggest different in 2 "you" doesn't really give order or strong recommendation it seems to be softer.

There is a big difference in the negative  "must not" or "don't have to"

Please also do a search for "must have to" on this site.  There are many questions about this pair.  In many cases there is no big difference in meaning, but "have to" is more common in everyday situations, with "must" in more formal obligations.

1 "must" vs "have to" 2 “You must” and “you have to” 3 Must vs. have to for traffic signs 4 "I must go to school" or "I have to go to school" Are they interchangeable or not?

@Mari-LouA I would like to know how to do that. I recall asking about how to do that on META and being shot down. And I still do not know.

@Lambie this isn't the first time you've asked me and I've never managed to succeed. Basically, it's looking for related posts “by hand“  and embedding the links.

@Mari-LouA OK, I will try it.

@Lambie if it's embedding one or more links in a comment which you are stuck on,  here's a very short tutorial

In both instances there is some form of obligation, specifics unknown. Either could fit a wide range of practical situations. For example, the utterances could refer to tasks on a list, or to some form of quid pro quo (perhaps you wanted to borrow the family car), or to the view of the speaker that you need to work on becoming neater.
Utterances do not have specific practical meaning until we impose a context (if they are presented to us in a vacuum as you're doing here) or until we relate them to the actual context in which they're spoken.
We can also establish a context in the utterance:

You have to clean your room if you want to borrow the car.
You really must clean your room, you slob.
You've done some laundry, fixed your little sister's tricycle, and taken out the trash. You still have to clean your room.


The modal must has a few meanings.  It takes sense A2
of Cambridge Dictionary:

must modal verb (NECESSARY)


used to show that it is necessary or very important that something happens in the present or future:
Meat must be cooked thoroughly.

Here it doesn't take B2:

must modal verb (PROBABLY)


used to show that something is very likely , probable, or certain to be true

or B1:

If you tell someone else that they must do something pleasant, you are emphasizing that you think it is a good idea to do that

With sense A2, the OP’s two examples have the same meaning.
Have to takes this definition in Cambridge Dictionary:

(used with the infinitive form of another verb) to need to or be forced to; must

and is consistent with sense A2 of must.
